# Python XML Error Causing Write Speed Issues? Weird Behavior?

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, lxml

Now I've been up bordering on 20 hours working on this by now so apologies if I'm missing something pretty straight forward.

This is a snippet of my current XML writing function:

```
def FileWrite():
    try:
        if os.path.exists("Temp.xml") == True:
            os.remove("Temp.xml")

        EventDumpCounter = 0

        for Eventes in EventTags:
            try:

                if os.path.exists("Temp.xml") == True:
                    tree = ET.parse("Temp.xml")
                    root = tree.getroot()
                if os.path.exists("Temp.xml") == False:
                    root = ET.Element("Refunds")
                    tree = ET.ElementTree(root)

                if float(EventCost[EventDumpCounter]) > float(Price[EventDumpCounter]):

                    if "Horse" in EventTags[EventDumpCounter]:
                        Eventes = ET.SubElement(root, "Event", type = EventTags[EventDumpCounter])
                        ET.SubElement(Eventes, "EventTime").text = str(EventTimes[EventDumpCounter])
                        ET.SubElement(Eventes, "EventName").text = str(EventName[EventDumpCounter])
                        ET.SubElement(Eventes, "EventLoc").text = str(EventLoc[EventDumpCounter])
                        ET.SubElement(Eventes, "EventSpace").text = str(EventSpace[EventDumpCounter])
                        ET.SubElement(Eventes, "EventCost").text = str(EventCost[EventDumpCounter])
                        ET.SubElement(Eventes, "EventPrice").text = str(EventPrice[EventDumpCounter])
                        ET.SubElement(Eventes, "EventParking").text = str(EventParking[EventDumpCounter])
                        ET.SubElement(Eventes, "EventDist").text = str(EventDist[EventDumpCounter])
                        tree.write("Temp.xml")

                EventDumpCounter +=1

            except:
                print "Problem writing XML"

    #except:
    except WindowsError, e:
        print "Problem creating XML 2"
        #e = sys.exc_info()[0]
        print e
```

So I need it to take everything from these lists an dump it into an XML file. It works in that state but it's much slower than I'd like and it's not a hardware problem.

I'm watching the Temp.xml go from 0KB to 16KB to 0KB to 50KB to 0KB to 80KB to 0KB to 200KB to 0KB to... you get the idea.

It's also taking longer to complete than I would normally expect to see. I swear I've worked with more data than this and it's been fine.

But based on the error and the time it takes I'm fairly sure I've done something wrong here. It might even be amazingly obvious but I just can't see it.

Am I missing something?

**Update:**

I've changed the way it calls FileWrite() so it won't keep triggering and that has removed the errors I was seeing before but it's still taking that long it's starting to look like a near infinite loop.

I've been asked to show how I call it so it's basically:

```
while 1:
        time.sleep(10)
        if OnlyOneXMLWriteCheck == 1:
            WriteThatThread = Thread(target = FileWrite)
            WriteThatThread.start()
            WriteThatThread.join()
```

OnlyOneXMLWriteCheck is set to 1 at the start of the script. 0 when the FileWrite function starts and then 1 again when it's done so it's preventing it from running more than once.

So it's not running multiple versions of itself any more but at least it was writing when it was doing that.

It is bouncing between 0KB 20KB 0KB 50KB 0KB 120KB 0KB 200KB etc... and it's been sitting there for a few minutes now. Wherever the problem is it's looking to me like its inside FileWrite() and it's bordering on an infinite loop.

It's not hardware issue though I do notice while it writes one CPU core is doing a lot more work than the rest.

[image: http://puu.sh/n5mv3/ba1c5d8974.png]

Maybe I could have threads write the elements in or something would that balance it over the other cores better perhaps?

**Further update**

If it's just writing one result it takes a millisecond. Before I can blink it's done so there's no reason for writing 100 to take close to 60 seconds. Something inside the loop is slowing it down.

I've tried doing it without checking if Temp.xml exists for the tree/root tags but that didn't do anything noticeable to the speed. Is it just going through all those lists doing it?

I don't think I can thread the writing because it would need to queue anyway to avoid writing over itself and messing the tags up.

I'm at a loss here.

Comment: Data comes in as strings and is appended to the lists. They're in the right place etc... When it does eventually write everything is in the right structure at least.

Comment: We appreciate your diagnostics but can you post some data for a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can reproduce your issue? Importantly, please provide script of how you call this defined function.

Comment: It was kind of awkward to show before. Fixed it up and fixed the Windows exceptions at the same time. Though the write speed is bordering on non existent.